# How can I extract netCDF to csv for a specific location?

Tags: python, csv, netcdf

I want to extract time series from a NetCDF to csv for a specific location.
I got this far with the code but it gives the TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

How can I overcome this issue?
Also, will this developed code have as output: time/mwp for the specific location?

```
import netCDF4 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset, num2date
from pylab import *
import xarray

f = netCDF4.Dataset('Wave_period_global.nc')
f.variables.keys()
print (f)

lat = f.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = f.variables['longitude'][:]
time_var = f.variables['time']
dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[:],time_var.units)
mwp = f.variables['mwp'][:]

print(lon.min(), lon.max())
print(lat.min(), lat.max())

longitude = 172
latitude = 50

def near(array,value):
    idx=(abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return idx

ix = near(lat, latitude)
iy = near(lon, longitude)

print ('Latitude =',ix)
print ('Longitude =',iy)

with open ('Wave_period_global.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for ln in range(len(lon)):
        for lt in range(len(lat)):
            value=f.variables['mwp'][0][lt][ln]
            dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[0],time_var.units)
            print(dtime,lat[lt],lon[ln,],value)
            filewriter.writerow([dtime,lat[lt],lon[ln,],value])
```

Comment: Which lib is giving you the Excepton? netCDF4 or csv? Your logic is off. ix and iy are found but not used. Your csv loop goes thru all the lats and lons when you need to loop thru all the times. You need to fix this before any answer can be given.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above. I'm leaving output as csv out of my answer to focus on your real question.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset, num2date

f = netCDF4.Dataset('Wave_period_global.nc')

lat = f.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = f.variables['longitude'][:]
time_var = f.variables['time']
# These are all datetime object.
dtime = netCDF4.num2date(time_var[:],time_var.units)
mwp = f.variables['mwp'][:]

print(lon.min(), lon.max())
print(lat.min(), lat.max())

longitude = 172
latitude = 50

def near(array,value):
    idx=(abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return idx

ix = near(lat, latitude)
iy = near(lon, longitude)

print ('Latitude =',ix)
print ('lat[] =', lat[ix])
print ('Longitude =',iy)
print ('lon[] =', lon[iy])

for i in range(len(dtime)):
  value=f.variables['mwp'][i][ix][iy]
  print(dtime[i],lat[ix],lon[iy,],value)
```

Comment: For the export to .csv; I tried to use 'w' instead of 'wb' but this changes the output of the .csv...
I'm still stuck on the export to .csv for now

Comment: dtime[i] is a python datetime object. For csv you need a string. Try datetime[i].isoformat()  to get the string.